# How can I change the image cell when it collapse?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

When I push the cell and collapse it I want the icon in the cell to change it's position

Here is the code for the table view:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell

            cell.serviciosLabel.text! = nameArr[indexPath.row]
            cell.serviciosImageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(imageArr[indexPath.row])")



        /* if (indexPath.row == 2){
         cell.serviciosExpandableView.image = UIImage(named: "\(imgcoll)")

         }

         */


        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            pushVentasTab() // pushVentaArticulos()
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            pushReporteDDia()
        } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
            if SelectedIndex == indexPath.row
            {

                if self.isCollapce == false
                {
                    self.isCollapce = true

                }else
                {
                    self.isCollapce = false
                }
            }else{
                self.isCollapce = true
            }
        }
        self.SelectedIndex = indexPath.row
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

I don't know how to change it, please have a look and help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what you have to do.
Create a swift file for your TableViewCell and using the IB connect the buttons and labels to the code.

Inside the tableCell swift file, declare a variable iconExpanded

```
var iconExpanded: Bool = false {
  didSet {
     setupCell()
   }
}
```

in setupCell() have the logic to change the image of the button

```
func setupCell(){
     if (iconExpanded) {
        // set the image to expanded
     } else {
       // set the image to closed
     }
}
```

Whenever there is a change in your table view set the collapsed or expanded value for the particular cell and reload the particular section.

```
let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: 0)
tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .automatic)
```

Lastly send the change in the state of the button to the cell.

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell

            cell.serviciosLabel.text! = nameArr[indexPath.row]
            cell.serviciosImageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(imageArr[indexPath.row])")
            cell.iconExpanded = <true for expand // false for collapse>  
        return cell
    }
```

nameArr is an array , create a struct to store the name and the expand state of each cell.

Comment: Thank you @Shubham

Comment: happy to help :) @JesusLoaizaHerrera